# What martial arts are similar to Systema?

Tags: ninjutsu, systema

I have been practicing Systema for about a year and unfortunately the school that I was attending closed down. There are no other Systema school anywhere within 100 miles of me. I am in love with this art and wanted to know if there is anything out there that is like it. So far I have found that ninjutsu and budo taijutsu are very similar. Is there anything else?

Comment: I thought Budo Taijutsu was a subset of the skills in "Ninjutsu".

Comment: @MichaelYamnato You are most likely right, I probably just confused budo taijutsu as a separate art

Comment: The other thing that makes it confusing is that one of the most popular ninjutsu-based styles is the Bujinkan system, so you may be thinking of that one (the other one that most people are familiar with is Stephen K. Hayes and his combination of mail-in instruction and books and his Shadows of Iga society).

Comment: How about Bakom or KFM (Keysi Fighting Method) ?

Answer (score 2):

I've done penjak silat for several years - the thing that interested me in Systema was a lot of similarity in movement around both blades and ground mobility.  You may find some schools that will give you some similar movements from the various styles of silat,  but penjak silat is also sometimes hard to find depending on where you are.

I do know if you look online, there's several Systema teachers giving exercises and drills by video and online.

Comment: … So, RPG chat was closed. Stupid thing. Nonetheless, thanks for the message. I did utterly miss all that whole thing. Shame to see you go but I support your decision. Still will be reading your blog. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on which aspects you're looking for. The focus on practical fighting methods might suggest looking at something like Krav Maga. If you're focused more on the "inner peace and calm" aspect, you might look into one of the more combative forms of Tai Chi, or to Aikido. Bankuei's suggestion above of Silat might also work, as it's got a bit of both.